# Elementos não carregando na Home page [Capybara - Ruby]

Tags: ruby, testes-automatizados, cucumber

Olá!

Estou realizando a automação de testes de um site, usando o Capybara, Ruby e Cucumber, onde o mesmo possui Lazy Loading, para carregamento de todos os produtos.

**Fluxo com problema:**
Home page -> Scroll até o primeiro produto -> Adiciona-ló ao carrinho

**O que está ocorrendo?** No "*Scroll até o primeiro produto*", devido o site possuir lazy loading, os produtos ficam exibindo o carregamento, porém, não carregam.
Isso só acontece no momento da **automação**, se **manualmente** movimentar um pouquinho a tela, os produtos são carregados, ficando assim visíveis (descartando problemas no site). 
Realizei a tentativa de simular o meu scroll manual, via automação porém, sem sucesso.

**Código:**

*Page object:*

```
require 'sections/headers/main_header.rb'
require 'sections/siders/side_menu.rb'
require 'sections/login/login.rb'
require 'sections/produto/box_produto.rb'


module ATG
  module Pages
    module Home
      class Home < SitePrism::Page
        set_url '/'


        section :main_header, ATG::Sections::Headers::MainHeader, 'div[class*="header-main"]'
        section :side_menu, ATG::Sections::Siders::SideMenu, 'div[class*="menu-main"]'
        section :login, ATG::Sections::Login::Login, 'div[id="modal-login"]'
        sections :box_produto, ATG::Sections::Produto::BoxProduto, 'div[class*="box-prod"]'


        element :modal_home, 'div[class="modal-close"]'



        def close_modal_home
          wait_for_modal_home
          modal_home.gclick
        end

        def scroll_produtos
          scroll_into_view('.page-content')
          sleep 3
        end

        def scroll_to_first_buyable
          scroll_into_view('.box-prod')
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

*Step definition*

```
    Quando("adicionar produto ao carrinho via home") do
  binding.pry
  @home.scroll_produtos
  @home.box_produto.first.greenify
  @box_produto = @home.box_produto.first
  @box_produto.add_product
  step "vejo as informações do produto"
  step "abrir o carrinho"
end
```

*Screenshoots:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]